# reusing for each loop for different game enemy objects

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm creating a game using Phaser, a Javascript framework. To load the enemies, I'm using a for each loop. The enemy data is read from a JSON file (exported from a tile editor).

However, my game has several types of enemies, ones that fly, run, jump. Each enemy uses a different sprite.

Is there a way to load each type of enemy without using several for each loops? 
When creating a new type of enemy (using the new keyword), I need to change the parameter from **enemy** to **flying enemy**

```
 SuperSmash.playState.prototype.createEnemies = function() {
   "use strict";
    this.enemies = this.add.group();
    var enemyArr = this.findObjectsByType('enemy', this.map,'objectslayer');



 **//I need to RESUSE this loop for each type enemy**

    var enemyz;
    enemyArr.forEach(function(element){
      enemyz = new SuperSmash.Enemy(this.game, element.x, element.y, 'enemy', +element.properties.velocity, this.map, this.player);
      this.enemies.add(enemyz);
    }, this);
  };



  findObjectsByType: function(targetType, tilemap, layer) {
    var result = [];
    tilemap.objects[layer].forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.properties.type == targetType) {
        element.y -= tilemap.tileHeight;
        result.push(element);
      }
    }, this);
    return result;
  },
```

Comment: Where do you store the different types of enemies there are?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
function createEnemies(type, enemies) {
  enemyArr.forEach(function(element){
    let enemyz = new SuperSmash.Enemy(this.game, element.x, element.y,
        type, +element.properties.velocity, this.map, this.player);
    enemies.add(enemyz);
  }, this);
};

SuperSmash.playState.prototype.createEnemies = function() {
  "use strict";
  this.enemies = this.add.group();
  var enemyArr = this.findObjectsByType('enemy', this.map,'objectslayer');
  createEnemies.call(this,'enemy',this.enemies);
}
```